# Regex to match blank line and comments in a file

Tags: ruby, regex, erb

How do I ignore comments or blank/empty lines in a file when reading? I thought `/^[\s#]*$/` would do the job but it didn't:

```
irb(main):180:0> open(inFile, 'r').each { |ln| puts ln if ln !~ /^[\s#]*$/ }
....
....
# and ..... ThIs Is A cOmMeNt .....
....
....
=> #<File:/tmp/running-instances.txt>
irb(main):181:0>
```

What am I missing here? Any help would be highly appreciated. Cheers!!

PS.

I can do the separately in two steps though:

```
open(inFile, 'r').each { |ln| next if ln =~ /^\s*$/; puts ln if ln !~ /#[^#]*$/ }
```

Comment: I think it's that `\s` doesn't work inside a character class.  It _is_ a character class.

Comment: @Gene: It does work, as `\w` for example.

Comment: @Gene: that's what I also thought in the first place but found there are number of cases where it does work. Cheers!!

Comment: You're right.  Character classes embedded in other character classes just form the union. I got it working with character classes.  See below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Match Comments and End-of-Line

```
/
  ^      # match start of line
  \s*    # match zero or more spaces
  (\#|$) # match comment symbol or end-of-line
/x
```

Compressed, the regex looks like this:

```
/^\s*(#|$)/
```

### Prose Explanation

The `\s*` means that any amount of whitespace immediately after the start of line, including **none at all**, can match. `(\#|$)` uses [alternation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Alternation), so either of the patterns within the parentheses can match. *NB: The backslash is only needed to escape the comment symbol when using the `x` [option](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Options), which ignores whitespace and comments in the regular expression; if you aren't using `x` then leave the backslash out.*

The pattern will therefore match start-of-line followed by optional whitespace, which must then be immediately followed by either a comment symbol or an end-of-line. Because the match is [anchored](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#label-Anchors), it will *not* match strings like `"foo # bar"` or `"  Array#string\n"` because they won't match the required pattern.

Comment: shortest so far and does work but trying to workout how it works. So, it's matches match zero or more spaces `\s*` in the beginning of the line: `^` - it covers the blank/empty lines but how does that also work for a line that starts with a `#`? Does that `\s*` and `(\#|$)` work as either-or? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers I've expanded the answer with a prose explanation that I believe answers your follow-up questions. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! didn't know `\s` also includes "none at all". BTW, what's that `x` used for? Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

How about this regex:

```
/^(#.*|\s*)$/
```

Comment: This doesn't match comment lines with leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you wanted to do.

```
^( *#.*| *?)$
```

The reason for the space before the `#` is, the comment could be indented a space or several.  If the line isn't a comment, we soak up as many spaces as we can, and see if that's all there is.

The space could be written as `[ ]` for clarity.

```
^([ ]*#.*|[ ]*?)$
```

Or to include tabs:

```
^([ \t]*#.*|[ \t]*?)$
```

[rubular](http://rubular.com/r/RmLp8YC1jU) (the blue stuff won't be matched)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler than the other answers, I think.

```
/^\s*(#.*)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `/^[\s#].*$/`, use `.` to match any characters.

Comment: This will match any line that begin with a space.

Comment: @sza: That's it: I was just a `.` away. Thanks a lot. Still the question though: `*` 0 or more then why still the extra `.` needed? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers dot matches for any single character, star is unlimited repetition. so `.*` matches any thing else

Answer (score 0):

```
open(inFile, 'r').each { |ln|  puts ln if ln !~ /^(\s+|#.+)$/ }
```

This regex looks for any amount of whitespace characters until the end of the line or a hash symbol followed by any characters until the end of the line. I believe [\s#]* looks for zero or more of whitespace characters or hash symbols, where adding a . will look for any character after the hash symbol as a match.

Answer (score 0):

To get back to the character class approach you were seeking...

There is no need to match the whole line.  You need only the part up to the first non-space.

So the idea is to match a leading prefix of spaces that ends in something other than a comment character.  Because the matcher will backtrack, you must also disallow the final character in the match from being whitespace.

```
open('foo.txt', 'r').each { |ln| ln.chomp!; puts ln if ln =~ /\A\s*[^#\s]/ }
```

I am assuming you want to allow leading spaces before comment characters.  Don't forget to chomp the newline to get an accurate replay of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Especially in **Java** worked for me

> (^((\s)*#+.*)$)|(^(\s)*$)

It considers arbitrary whitespaces prior an '#' and empty lines with just whitespaces. So

> string.matches("(^\s*#+.*$)|(^\s*$)")

returns true for all comment lines and empty lines.